# C11 <thread.h> in GCC?

Tags: c, gcc, c11

I’m trying to compile some C11 code using `thread.h`, but I can’t. I've recompiled GCC (running 4.6.2 now), and I’m trying to compile with `gcc -std=c1x file.c -o file`. I can do this in g++ (using the `thread` library, that is) but I can’t in C. Is `thread.h` not included in the GCC distribution yet?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does any C library implement C11 threads for GNU/Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24557728/does-any-c-library-implement-c11-threads-for-gnu-linux)

Comment: For any relatively recent version of gcc, you can use `-std=c11` rather than `-std=c1x`.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

The standard C11 header for threading is `<threads.h>`, not `<thread.h>`. See section 7.26 of the [N1570 draft](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf).

Most of the C standard library, including stdio for example, is not included in the gcc distribution. Instead, gcc depends on whatever runtime library is provided by the operating system. That generally includes both the headers (like `<threads.h>`) and the actual code that implements the library.

For most Linux systems (or GNU/Linux if you prefer), the library is GNU's glibc; for other systems it will be something else.

So the real question is probably when glibc, or whichever C library you're using, will support C11's threading features.

[glibc adds support for C11 threads in version 2.28](https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=14092). Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS system currently still uses glibc 2.27. Again, this applies only to implementations using GNU libc, not to all gcc-based implementations. Mentioned by WorldSEnder in a comment.

UPDATE: Ubuntu 18.10 (not an LTS (Long Term Support) release) has glibc 2.28, which supports `<threads.h>`. Also, as [user2548688's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28480873/827263) points out, the [musl C library](http://www.musl-libc.org/) supports `<threads.h>`. On Ubuntu, you can install the `musl-dev` package and use the `musl-gcc` command.

(Note that a few parts of the library, those most closely tied to the compiler, *are* provided by gcc itself.  The threading library *probably* isn't one of them, but certainly some compiler support is required.)

Comment: Most Linux systems use glibc, some (like modern Debian and its derivatives) use EGLIBC. A few other system use other alternates.

Comment: [glibc adds support with version 2.28](https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=14092)

Comment: "modern debian uses EGLIBC" To clarify, Debian and it's derivatives used eglibc for releases 6 and 7 (circa 2009-2015) but switched to glibc in debian 8. As of early 2020 (Debian 10), Debian continues to use glibc.

The original comment was posted in 2013, so it was, of course, correct at the time

Answer (score 9):

Further information about this can be found [here](http://cygwin.com/ml/libc-alpha/2011-12/msg00051.html).

> ...
>   (Atomics - stdatomic.h - are optional, and will probably need to wait for 
>   associated language features to be implemented in GCC 4.8.  I'd guess that 
>   the optional threading interfaces in threads.h and bounds-checking 
>   interfaces in Annex K aren't wanted for glibc for now, although they could 
>   potentially go in separate libraries.

My guess is that we won't see this implemented for quite some time, at least not in standard glibc and gcc (sourced post provides some insight). My personal guess is something like one year, it will take probably something like 2 years until it will be stable enough for production use. Thats 2k14 (assert(survival_2012)) :P

Comment: August 27, 2014 (2 years and 7 months later): no plans on developing `threads.h` in GLIBC yet.

Comment: Yep, seems that I was wrong unfortunatedly (so native windows threads / posix threads have to do for the forseeable future).
For some reason nobody is pushing for support of portable threads :/

Comment: [glibc 2.28, August 2018](https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=14092) (mentioned in my answer).

Answer (score 6):

To quote from the GCC [standards page](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Standards.html) about C11:

> GCC has limited incomplete support for parts of this standard

While I only have GCC 4.6.1, I do not have a "thread.h" header file anywhere on my system.

Neither the changes pages for [4.6](http://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-4.6/changes.html) nor [4.7](http://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-4.7/changes.html) mentions threads.

---

There are "threads" mentioned in the 4.7 changes page, but nothing that seems to have anything to do with it in a C11 context. Also, nothing about C11 is mentioned in the upcomming [4.8](http://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-4.8/changes.html) page.

Comment: This is not quite true: 4.7 does mention threads.  I'm not sure if it did when you posted, but it certainly does now.

Answer (score 2):

musl libc has C11  http://www.musl-libc.org/
glibc doesn't threads.h support yet

Comment: [glibc 2.28, August 2018](https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=14092) (mentioned in my answer).