# clang c11 threads.h not found

Tags: c, xcode, clang, c11, threads.h

I am trying to setup a c11 thread example in xcode... but it doesn't seem to have the threads.h header, though it isn't complaning about the macro described here:
http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf

> __STDC_NO_THREADS__The integer constant 1, intended to indicate that the implementation does not support the <threads.h> header.

[image: showing dialect]
[image: showing error]

Comment: Looks like it didn't find the `threads.h` file.

Comment: that is what it looked like to me too :) that is supposed to be part of the startdard library in c11 if the __STDC_NO_THREADS__ macro isn't 1

Comment: I guess you ought to check that folder and see if `threads.h` is actually in there, and if it is, see if the compiler has access to it.

Comment: doesn't seem to be in the xcode bundle... according to `find  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents -name threads.h`

Comment: try `#if !defined(__STDC_NO_THREADS) || __STDC_NO_THREADS__`

Comment: @Kevin, there we go... there should be a magic `__ALL_MACROS__` macro... or is there... train of thought de-railed

Answer (score 3):

Looks like almost nothing supports the threads feature in C11... maybe I will try to get it into clang...

Comment: That might be simpler if you are willing to build upon a different C library. I recently looked into musl (http://www.musl-libc.org/), and there such a task seems to be doable. If you would be satisfied with a wrapper around POSIX, my P99 (p99.gforge.inria.fr) could be sufficient.

Comment: I haven't ever looked at any alternatives (I will now)... it will need to be in glibc / gcc / clang eventually... if it is only a wrapper for posix threads where they are supported... then I think that would suffice.

Comment: `threads.h` now works on Linux (since glibc 2.28,  musl 1.1.5), and FreeBSD (link with `-lstdthreads`). Still no mainstream support on macOS or Windows though. But now that it is supported on both Linux and FreeBSD, the odds that macOS and Windows will join the C11 threads party is higher. Actually, the Pelles C compiler on Windows already does support it, but I wouldn't exactly consider that "mainstream support" (which would be MSVC and/or MinGW-w64)

Comment: @simonKissane, at least `__STDC_NO_THREADS__` is defined now... so I guess it is at least compliant.

Answer (score 3):

Just in case anyone is looking this up in 2021+, Apple still doesn't support this, and likely never will. As others have stated, `pthreads` is by far the best bet. Note that widely, C11 threads are not supported. I would go as far as to say `pthreads` is more portable in most circumstances.

From a development perspective, C11 threads are much too limited, and obfuscate user space vs. kernel space implementation features, along with implementation attributes.

If you really need C11 threads I would recommend doing one of three things.

1. Don't.
2. Use a cross-platform library: https://github.com/tinycthread/tinycthread seems to do a good job.
3. Write your own polyfill. The library I just mentioned tries to support a bunch of platforms (though it's inactive now), but anyone with a little bit of experience with pthreads and win32 threads will have no trouble (but, maybe a headache) writing a polyfill. I actually did this the other day out of interest, and it took just a few hundred lines, not too bad. For any project that will use it alot, this will give more control over usage.

The good thing to note is some other C11 features are supported on OSX, like C11 Atomics, which complementing would be impossible without a lot of ASM knowledge.

Comment: Yes... it was naive of the committee to release thread support as late as 2011 and think it would be implemented, when de facto standards like pthreads were already established more than 10 years earlier. I don't know the reason why they didn't make pthreads a standard C lib, but I very much doubt the reasons were technical. More likely related to politics and prestige.

Comment: @Lundin Yes. the C standard has always been very limited in scope intentionally. Development goes slowly, feature/library additions are few, and compatibility is the main focus of the committee.

Answer (score 1):

With the clang on my machine (v. 3.2 on ubuntu/linux) that feature test macro isn't defined. Support for that feature will need support in the C library, that usually doesn't come with the compiler. So basically the answer for clang will not be much different than for gcc, they usually build upon the same C library, namely glibc, see [here for answer for gcc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8859394/c11-thread-h-in-gcc/8860111#8860111).

Answer (score 0):

> it doesn't seem to have the `threads.h` header, though **it isn't complaining**

C11 has 2 specs about `__STDC_NO_THREADS__`

> 7.26 Threads 
>   Implementations that define the macro `__STDC_NO_THREADS__` need not provide
>   this header nor support any of its facilities. C11 N1570  §7.26.1 2
>
> `__STDC_NO_THREADS__` The integer constant 1, intended to indicate that the
>   implementation does not support the `<threads.h>` header. C11 N1570  §6.10.8.3  1

Per §7.26.1 2:

```
#ifdef __STDC_NO_THREADS__
#error "No threading support"
#else
#include <threads.h>
#endif
```

Per §6.10.8.3:

```
#if defined(__STDC_NO_THREADS) && __STDC_NO_THREADS__ == 1
#error "No threading support"
#else
#include <threads.h>
#endif

// Certainly this can be simplified to
#if defined(__STDC_NO_THREADS) && __STDC_NO_THREADS__
```

or per [What is the value of an undefined constant used in #if?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5085392/2410359) to

```
#if __STDC_NO_THREADS__
```

This matches OP's code, so I would have expected that to work with a compliant C11 compiler.

---

Yet it looks like OP has a [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16244153/clang-c11-threads-h-not-found#comment23240258_16244153) per [@Kevin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16244153/clang-c11-threads-h-not-found#comment23240204_16244153).  That may be a false solution as  `__STDC_NO_THREADS` looks like a typo (missing trailing `__`).

```
#if !defined(__STDC_NO_THREADS) || __STDC_NO_THREADS__
```

Answer (score -20):

In C++11, you want to `#include <thread>`, not `threads.h`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

void fun() { std::cout << "fun!" << std::endl; }

int main() {
    std::thread t ( fun );
    t.join ();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: true, this is specifically about the much less hyped C11