# C11 GCC threads.h not found?

Tags: c, multithreading, c11

The following code

```
#include <threads.h>
```

Gives me this error:

```
fatal error: threads.h: No such file or directory
```

Using the latest GCC and Clang with -std=c11.

Is C11 threading not supported by GCC and Clang? Or is there a hack (or something to install) to get it? I'm just using Ubuntu 14.04 with the gcc and clang packages from the Ubuntu repo.

Comment: The number of compilers fully supporting c11 and/or threads.h is negative. :(

Comment: C11 threads, when they eventually become supported, will be supported by the C *library* and not the compiler proper.  At least two people are talking about implementing C11 threads for glibc as a GSoC project this summer.  In the meantime, you may find the `pthread.h` API suspiciously similar, albeit with much longer names for everything.

Comment: In RHEL, there is no `threads.h` but there is `pthread.h`. In solaris there is `thread.h`.

Comment: @Zack any references? This was the only [glibc thread](https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=14092) I could find.

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour e.g. https://sourceware.org/ml/libc-alpha/2014-03/msg00451.html

Comment: @Zack thank you, added the link into my answer.

Comment: A lot of standardization is “blessing” existing widely-implemented extensions that are considered a good idea, but experience shows that the lead time between a new feature appearing in the C standard and actually being widely implemented by compilers/libraries is more like “10 years to never” than “up to 3 years”.

Comment: @Emmet */me wordlessly slides the bottle of whiskey down the bar toward you*

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C11 <thread.h> in GCC?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8859394/c11-thread-h-in-gcc)

Comment: See also [Does any C library implement C11 threads for GNU/Linux?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24557728/827263)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The `gcc` document [C11 status](http://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/C11Status) indicates that it does not support threading, it says:

> Threading [Optional] |  Library issue (not implemented)

As the document indicates this is not really a `gcc` or `clang` issue but `glibc` issue. As Zack pointed out it looks like [there may be work under way soon](https://sourceware.org/ml/libc-alpha/2014-03/msg00451.html) to get support for this into `glibc` but that won't help you now.
You can use [this](https://github.com/jtsiomb/c11threads/blob/master/c11threads.h)  in the meantime.

#### Fixed for glibc 2.28

According the [Bug 14092 - Support C11 threads](https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=14092#c10) this is fixed in glibc 2.28:

> Implemented upstream by:
>
> 9d0a979 Add manual documentation for threads.h
> 0a07288 nptl: Add test cases for ISO C11 threads
> c6dd669 nptl: Add abilist symbols for C11 threads
> 78d4013 nptl: Add C11 threads tss_* functions
> 918311a nptl: Add C11 threads cnd_* functions
> 3c20a67 nptl: Add C11 threads call_once functions
> 18d59c1 nptl: Add C11 threads mtx_* functions
> ce7528f nptl: Add C11 threads thrd_* functions
>
> It will be included in 2.28.

Comment: Thank you. So neither GCC nor Clang support C11 threading then? I will have to regress back to POSIX threads then :-(

Comment: @lucasart looks to be the case

Comment: I wish I had read this yesterday. [The Bugzilla for threading in `glibc`](https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=14092) is still open (2+ years). @lucasart : POSIX threads seems hardly a regression; nearly identical interface, "portable", *and* implemented. :) Indeed, compiling against [`glibc` 2.19](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/libc.html) reports `__STDC_NO_THREADS__` is `1`. See also [this SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8859394/c11-thread-h-in-gcc) for additional links. pthreads it is (or C++11 `std::thread`, which btw depends on `-pthread`...).

Comment: Apparently some movement on the [glibc side](https://sourceware.org/ml/libc-alpha/2015-06/msg00894.html)

Comment: I can `#include <threads.h>` now with Glibc 2.31 (Ubuntu 20.04)

Answer (score 6):

[Musl](http://www.musl-libc.org/) support C11 `<threads.h>`.

In Debian install `musl-tools`, and then compile with `musl-gcc`. I am working on  bootstrapping Debian with Musl instead of Glibc.

Also see [this](https://github.com/jtsiomb/c11threads/blob/master/c11threads.h).

Comment: In Ubuntu the linked header *c11threads.h* causes a bunch of errors. E.g. `PTHREAD_MUTEX_TIMED_NP` being undeclared. Searching says it should be in the included `pthreads.h`, but it seems isn't.

Comment: @Hi-Angel You either need to use the -std=gnu11 compiler flag instead of -std=c11 or you need to use a #define _GNU_SOURCE before including that c11threads.h  file.

Comment: Works on debian 9.13 Sunday, February 28 2021.

Answer (score 1):

While C11 threads has not been implemented yet, C++11 threads have been implemented and they have similar functionality.  Of course, C++11 may be an unacceptable solution, in which case the prior comments about POSIX threads are your best hope.

Answer (score 1):

Threads have been merged into mainline Glibc and are available for example on my Ubuntu 20.04. Unfortunately I don't seem to have any manual pages for the function. But this works:

```
#include <threads.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int hello_from_threading(void *arg) {
    printf("Thread about to take a nap...\n");
    thrd_sleep(&(struct timespec) { .tv_sec = 3 }, NULL);
    printf("Woke up from 3 second slumber\n");
    return 42;
}

int main(void) {
    thrd_t thread;
    thrd_create(&thread, hello_from_threading, NULL);
    int res;
    printf("A thread was started\n");
    thrd_join(thread, &res);
    printf("Thread ended, returning %d\n", res);
}
```

and testing it:

```
% gcc threading.c -o threading -lpthread
% ./threading
A thread was started
Thread about to take a nap...
Woke up from 3 second slumber
Thread ended, returning 42
```

Comment: Is there a reason why it is necessary to link to pthreads to actually compile the code when the intention is to use standard threads from C11?

Answer (score -1):

You can compile it with the command;

```
clang c-prog-with-threads_h.c
```

without using -lpthread now. (And latest versions of compilers did not need to specify **std=c11**, because of it is default).

**clang version 14.0.1, platform: Termux app, Android.**