# How can I understand what standard my libraries are and to what standard gcc compiles in my computer?

Tags: c, gcc, standards

This is from my terminal:

```
Korays-MacBook-Pro:~ koraytugay$ gcc --version
Configured with: --prefix=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 6.1.0 (clang-602.0.49) (based on LLVM 3.6.0svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin14.3.0
Thread model: posix
```

There are 3 C standards as far as I know, ANSI C, C99 and C11.

How can I know which library I have and what my compiler supports?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17206568/what-is-the-difference-between-c-c99-ansi-c-and-gnu-c-a-general-confusion-reg

EDIT: sorry, that only explains the differences between the standards

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to find the documentation for your compiler and/or operating system and it's not always clearly documented.

---

> Apple LLVM version 6.1.0 (clang-602.0.49) (based on LLVM 3.6.0svn)

This corresponds to Xcode 6.3.

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/releasenotes/DeveloperTools/RN-Xcode/Chapters/Introduction.html

Also anything in the LLVM 3.5 release should be in this version of the compiler: the compiler is 'based on the llvm 3.6 svn branch, which exists prior to LLVM.org's 3.6 release (a bit confusing, I know).

http://clang.llvm.org/cxx_status.html

They don't have a similar handy page for C version support, however.

http://llvm.org/releases/3.5.0/tools/clang/docs/UsersManual.html#differences-between-various-standard-modes

In fact it looks to me like the documentation doesn't even accurately reflect clang 3.5's C11 support.

---

So basically, if the documentation doesn't clearly cover it, you just have to be familiar with the compiler.

Xcode 6.3 supports C language features for C89/C90, C94, C99, and C11. I believe OS X offers full library support up to C99. OS X does not include an implementation of the C11 standard library, however some C11 headers may be provided by the compiler. `<threads.h>` isn't, however.

Comment: @alk One of the ISO documents was released in 1994 (there were also updates in 1995 and 1996). I've never bothered with it, but the [documentation](http://llvm.org/releases/3.5.0/tools/clang/docs/UsersManual.html#differences-between-various-standard-modes) says it's supported. However it seems like this might be another inaccuracy in the docs, since clang gives an error for `-std=c94`.

Comment: Oh I see. And looking up the gcc docs reveals that the argument to  `-std` shall be `iso9899:199409` for this then, which obviously isn't commonly known (anymore) ... :-))

Comment: Interesting, that works for clang too, but the clang docs say to use `c94`.

Comment: Here's the source for the full list of language modes supported by the current version of clang: http://llvm.org/svn/llvm-project/cfe/trunk/include/clang/Frontend/LangStandards.def

Comment: @alk: C94 is probably C90 with corrections and ammendment AMD1, which added the wide char functions.

Answer (score 4):

Clang support all three standards and more (“gnu99” from GCC, …). You can find out in the [documentation](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/UsersManual.html#differences-between-various-standard-modes) of the commandline option `-std` which is used to choose them.

Comment: You just beat me to it, ++

Comment: My compiler can not find <threads.h> so I think I either do not have the C11 library or my compiler does not support it?

Comment: @KorayTugay It should be noted that while the C standards describe **compilation platforms** in which standard libraries and compiler per se are not distinguished (and indeed it would be harmful to try to), the Open Source world insists on treating them as distinct projects. I could give you more examples: compiler translation of struct assignment as memcpy calls (not valid with strict standard memcpy implementations), floating-point rounding mode stuff (that the compiler should be aware of to be correct and cannot be left to the library), …

Comment: @KorayTugay see [C11 GCC threads.h not found?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22875545/1708801)

Answer (score 4):

http://clang.llvm.org/docs/UsersManual.html#id39

Use the `-std` command-line flag, e.g. `-std=c11` or `-std=c++11` to select the standard.

Comment: I am still seeing this: Korays-MacBook-Pro:hello2 koraytugay$ gcc hello.c -std=c11
hello.c:5:2: warning: implicit declaration of function 'quick_exit' is invalid in C99

Comment: @KorayTugay The message means it's invalid in C99 and later.

Comment: If you meant C++11, the option should be -std=c++11, not -std=c11